# How to style hyperlink after scheme is removed with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

So I am trying to display a url that is caught by Javascript. It is returned to JS in the form http://i.mygreatsite.com, but I would like to cut the schema off to make it cleaner, and have the actual code look something like

```
<a href=http://i.mygreatsite.com>i.mygreatsite.com</a>
```

Before I tried doing this, I had to set some special attributes on the url, namely setting target to blank so it would open in a new tab and changing the color of the hyperlink to black, as the rest of the links on the page are blue. I went about it like this:

```
  init: function() {
                this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = responseText;
                    a.innerHTML = responseText;
                    a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                    a.style.color="black";
                    span.appendChild(a);
                    span.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; bottom: -28px; left: 3px; right: 3px;  height: 28px; word-wrap: break-word; line-height: 28px; text-overflow: ellipsis; ");

                    file.previewTemplate.appendChild(span);

                });
            }
```

Everything worked fine with it, but when I went to remove the schema I did it by using regex:

```
repl = responseText.replace(/(https?:\/\/(\S+))/i, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>");
a.href = repl;
a.innerHTML = repl;
a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
a.style.color="black";
```

Now the schema is removed, but none of the attributes I set previously that were working before are there now. The URL is blue and opens in the same tab. Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: Dont know why the strange behavior, probably because you are setting a tag to both href and your innerhtml. Regex is fun, but in this case why not set href to the original responsetext, as this is the URL of the link, and innerhtml to responsetext.slice(8,responsetext.length) <- this will slice the first 8 characters of the string, thus removing https://

Comment: I also need it to remove http://, not just https://

Comment: ah k, though I think the problem is that you are making a complete tag in your string. I think you need to set the href to the URL = 'h ttp://i.mygreatsite.com' and the innerHTML to the replacement text 'i.mygreatsite.com'. The way you do in now is you set them both to: <a href=h ttp://i.mygreatsite.com>i.mygreatsite.com</a> so you get a very weird construct, probably a href tag within a href tag, and browsers will try to make sense of this in probably unexpected ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've ended up with is an anchor within another anchor:

```
<a target="_blank" style="XXX"><a href="http://myurl">myurl</a></a>
```

That's because of setting the `innerHTML` of the anchor you're trying to create. Setting styles on an element will not cascade (you should really use CSS Stylesheets instead) and of course the `target` element will not apply as it's technically **not** the hyperlink you're clicking on!

Instead, just set the `innerHTML` using the `$2` result of your Regex.

**Edit**

So your updated code would need to be similar to:

```
repl = responseText.replace(/(https?:\/\/(\S+))/i, "$2");
a.href = responseText;
a.innerHTML = repl;
a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
a.style.color="black";
//Or if you wanted to use CSS stylesheets
a.className = "myCssClass"
```

Comment: So I tried doing: a.innerHTML = responseText.replace(/(https?:\/\/(\S+))/i, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>");, and the result still doesn't have the styles applied on it. How could I set these using a stylesheet when the link is dynamically generated and will show up after the page loads?

Comment: not sure if you're using JQuery, but in native JS you can set the `class` attribute using the `className` property of the DOM object. See W3Schools: [HTML DOM className Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp)

Comment: Updated the answer with a quick idea of what I meant. I hope that clarifies.